# Finding MMS size limit?

Tags: java, android, png, jpeg, mms

I am writting an Android app that sends PNGs across MMS. An issue I encountered is that larger images get compressed into JPGs. Because the image format must be losseless I need to know the user's MMS byte limit (not standardized across carriers apparently). I've seen 300KB as a rule of thumb, but I was wondering if there was a way to programatically find the max MMS size so I can avoid compression. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Android M and above there's a public API for this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CarrierConfigManager.html

Before M the API is private. However, you can easily get access to the values. Android relies on predefined  values that are stored in XML files in MMS service (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Mms/+/lollipop-dev/res/). You can either import those values into your app, or extract them from the /system/priv-app/MmsService/MmsService.apk in run time (the file is world-readable).